# Copy files from one zip to other zip - ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip

Tags: .net, vb.net, zip, clone, sharpziplib

i would copy files from one ZipFile to another ZipFile.

Why it issnt so easy?

```
' Copy files from b.zip to a.zip
Dim a As New ZipFile(CurDir() & "\a.zip")
Dim b As New ZipFile(CurDir() & "\b.zip")

a.BeginUpdate()

For Each c As ZipEntry In b
    a.Add(c) 'Error: ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipException - Entry cannot have any data
Next

a.CommitUpdate()
a.Close()
```

I use the https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib Library on .NET 4.5 Visual Basic.

Could anyone give me a tip?

Answer (score 0):

If your destination zip file is same as source then copy whole Zip file and Rename it, why your doing one by one files.........

Comment: Content from a.zip:
1.txt

Content from b.zip:
2.txt
3.txt


I would test the system and i would know how i can opy single files from one zip archive to another zip archive.

Comment: You need to use the libraries like SharpZipLib or DotNetZip. No need to unzip the file.

Comment: Is there a example for ShareZipLib or DotNetZip how to copy files from one zip to other zip without unzip? I use ShareZipLib ^^

Comment: its in C#

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987072/sharpziplib-can-you-add-a-file-without-it-copying-the-entire-zip-first

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107966/c-extract-a-zipped-file-only-without-the-folder) one also

Comment: Now i tried to copy the files like your example andy.
-> http://pastebin.com/w8Dz6jMa
But it doesnt work... The file was added to file. YAY!
But they have no content -.- (size = 0)
If i remove .size = 0, i get the error like the person in your example...

Comment: Now i solved this problem with rebuild the archiv...
But i could not delete any entries -.-
`a.Delete(a.EntryByIndex(a.FindEntry("test", True)))` <- FindEntry is != -1 ;)